# GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 12.2.0, was not found vmware

Tags: vmware

I get this message after I installed VMware. I saw a similar topic here in askubuntu, but this solution didn't work for me.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/y5EQF08]

Comment: Do: `sudo apt install build-essential`, a meta-package that installs the compiler, libraries, tools, that you need.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details; *deb* packages are built for specific releases, and we currently don't know yours.

Comment: This title will collect a flood of like problems created by the Jan. hwe upgrade to the Ubuntu 22.04 kernel version 6.5.The 6.5 kernel is compiled with gcc-12, and so any module compile needs that compiler version. You need to install it yourself (like many answers below), until Canonical adds a fix (dependency?).  Do add yourself to the Nvidia module bug 2051457, since one such fix will fix all modules.

Answer (score 6):

I took an update today on my Ubuntu 22.04 and encountered the error with VMware Workstation 16 Pro `16.2.4 build-20089737` shown in the question here.

```
GNU C Compiler (gcc) version 12.3.0, was not found. If you installed it in a non-default path you can specify the path below. Otherwise refer to your distribution's documentation for installation instructors and click Refresh to search again in default locations.
```

I've used VMWare every day since this OS was fresh installed in 2022.

There were three problems to fix:

**Missing gcc 12**

My `gcc --version` is 11.4.0. I checked `ls /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-*` and version 12 was not there.

```bash
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/ppa -y
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install g++-12 gcc-12
```

Then try again.

**skb_gso_segment undefined**

The build breaks because of gcc header changes. The VMWare build provides a log file like `/tmp/vmware-user/vmware_1234.log` that shows the compiler error.

This particular function, `skb_gso_segment`, has moved to a new header that VMWare `bridge.c` does not `#include`.

To see for yourself the header where this function is defined, `cd /usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-14/include/net` and `grep skb_gso_segment *`.

To fix VMWare code:

```bash
$ sudo su
$ cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

# back up original tar file
$ cp vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.original

# change the code
$ tar -xvf vmnet.tar
$ nano vmnet-only/bridge.c
```

After the `#include <linux/netdevice.h>`, add

```c
   #include <net/gso.h>
```

Save and exit. Then rebuild the tar file.

```bash
$ tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
$ exit
```

Then try again.

**__pte_offset_map undefined**

Next the build fails because a function has changed names. In VMWare Workstation 17, the code in `pgtbl.h` was changed like this by VMWare:

```c
#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(6,5,0)
            pte_t *pte = pte_offset_kernel(pmd, addr);
#else
            pte_t *pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, addr);
#endif
```

To fix v16, I made a similar change.

```bash
$ sudo su
$ cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source

# back up original tar file
$ cp vmmon.tar vmmon.tar.original

# change the code
$ tar -xvf vmmon.tar
$ nano vmmon-only/include/pgtbl.h
```

In the editor, search down to `pte_offset_map` and change it to `pte_offset_kernel`.

Save and exit. Then rebuild the tar file.

```bash
$ tar -cf vmmon.tar vmmon-only
$ exit
```

Then try again.

This got me back in operation.

Comment: Brilliant! Just notice the `__pte_offset_map` should be `pte_offset_map`. Also, will this fix affect future updates?

Comment: Good catch, typo fixed!

Comment: Hopefully if a future update to vmware reverts the changes to the tar files, it will contain these fixes.

Comment: just ran into this issue after accepting/applying an Ubuntu 22.04 security update; in my case I'm running VMWare Workstation 17 Pro (17.0.2); followed the steps exactly as outlined and ... tada ... I'm up and running again. Thanks for the taking the time to list/detail each step, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I too had this issue and what resolved it for me was as simple as

```
sudo apt install gcc-12 libgcc-12-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

The *build-essential* package is a metapackage which includes the following (in 22.04):

- libc6-dev | libc-dev
- gcc (>= 4:10.2)
- g++ (>= 4:10.2)
- make
- dpkg-dev
  (>= 1.17.11)

Installing it with:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install build-essential
```

should solve the problem, ensuring you have all the basic C and C++ compiler tools available on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Installing WS Pro 17.5 build 22583795 on Ubuntu 22.04 and also encountered this compiler not found message.

My gcc was showing as the latest version installed but was 11.04.

I tried the basic approach and ran **sudo apt install g++-12 gcc-12**

I closed and reopened WS Pro and it now said libraries needed to be compiled.  I clicked OK and the setup wizard continued successfully.